# python goalseek to solve for a discount rate variable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize

I know how to use numpy irr and npv, however, I am struggling with solving for a rate that makes my NPV = 0 when one of the cashflows (the terminal value) is dependent on this rate. Effectively I need to find a way to write a goalseek function where I set my NPV to 0 by changing a discount factor for all my cashflows. So solving for something like this:

1. cash outlay (in this case market capitalization value, a negative value)
2. cashflow_1 / (1 + rate + spread)^1
3. cashflow_2 / (1 + rate + spread)^2
4. cashflow_3 / (1 + rate + spread)^3
5. ((cashflow_3 * (1 + lt_growth_rate)) / (rate + spread - lt_growth_rate)) / (1 + rate + spread)^3

and I need to find where the spread measure makes my NPV = the market cap value, step 0, i.e. a zero value.

here is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton, fsolve


def fn(x):
    return np.npv(x, [-tst['mkt_cap'][i] + (tst['fcfe_1'][i]/(1+ x + tst['10y_tsy'][i])) + (tst['fcfe_2'][i]/(1+ x + tst['10y_tsy'][i])**2) + (tst['fcfe_3'][i]/(1+x+tst['10y_tsy'][i])**3) + ((tst['fcfe_3'][i] * (1+terminal_growth))/(tst['10y_tsy'][i] + x - terminal_growth))])

[newton(fn,x0=0) for x in range(len(tst))]
```

Ive also tried using the GoalSeek function from here (https://github.com/DrTol/GoalSeek_Python)

like so:

```
[print(GoalSeek(fn,goal,x0)) for i in range(len(tst))]
```

where goal is 0 and x0=.05, a guess value

any help would be much appreciated!! thank you.

edit: and here is a snippet of the dataframe, from the main dataframe not "tst" which was just a slice I was testing on:

where "10y_tsy" is the 10-year government bond per issuer (they are different values for different countries of domicile), fwiw.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uURd3.png)

Comment: How is `lt_growth_rate` calculated?  The question implies it's a function of rate+spread.  Could you show the function to calculate it?  Showing an example set of data would probably help too.

Comment: Thanks - so lt_growth_rate is a static variable, defined as .01 (so 1% growth). let me edit the post to show some of the dataframe (first time posting, let's see if I can do that!) Thx again.

Comment: I tried using the first data set.  The function shoots off to +- infinity at around r = -1.0, r = .015, r = 1.33.  These discontinuities make it very difficult to solve.  Try plotting a graph of a few examples and see where the NPV equals zero.

Comment: Another thought.  If you use `.01 + '10yr_tsy'` as your initial guess the chances of finding a solution will be higher.

Comment: Thanks @TlsChris I solved it! I ended up using fsolve in a function and then applying it to the whole dataframe. Appreciate your help.